# Динамическое добавление фрагментов в Tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Есть активити с табами, количество табов задается при создании, я же хочу добавлять и удалять их динамически.

Попробовал сделать следующим образом. Но получаю

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
```

Подумал что это из-за того что в списке фрагментов mFragmentList нету нового фрагмента и попробовал его добавить туда вручную, но не помогло, возможно я все неправильно делаю, вообщем прошу помощи..

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<Fragment> fragments = adapter.getmFragmentList();
                fragments.add(new ListContactsFragment());
                adapter.setmFragmentList(fragments);
                adapter.addFragment(new ListContactsFragment(), "TEST");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContactsFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new ListIncomingFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private  List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private  List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        public List<Fragment> getmFragmentList() {
            return mFragmentList;
        }

        public void setmFragmentList(List<Fragment> mFragmentList) {
            this.mFragmentList = mFragmentList;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переписать ваш метод `setmFragmentList` вот так:

```
public void setmFragmentList(List<Fragment> mFragmentList) {
    this.mFragmentList.clear();
    this.mFragmentList.addAll(mFragmentList);
}
```